# combined 2 selectors when same text appeared twice

Tags: css, xpath, css-selectors

I want to verify the `00:01:33` is appeared next to `Audio Length`

How do I combined 2 selectors into one?

I tried this and not working. because there are two '00:01:33' appeared in same page.

```
//span[@class='ant-descriptions-item-label'][contains(.,'Audio Length')]//following::span[text()='00:01:33']
```

[image: screenshot]

outer HTML of this table to be inspected:

```html
<table style="outline: green dotted 2px !important;">
   <tbody>
      <tr class="ant-descriptions-row">
         <td class="ant-descriptions-item" colspan="1">
            <div class="ant-descriptions-item-container"><span class="ant-descriptions-item-label" style="">Audio Length</span><span class="ant-descriptions-item-content" style="">00:01:33</span></div>
         </td>
         <td class="ant-descriptions-item" colspan="1">
            <div class="ant-descriptions-item-container"><span class="ant-descriptions-item-label">Model Used</span><span class="ant-descriptions-item-content">cs-sg-16k</span></div>
         </td>
         <td class="ant-descriptions-item" colspan="1">
            <div class="ant-descriptions-item-container"><span class="ant-descriptions-item-label">Original Sample Rate</span><span class="ant-descriptions-item-content">8000Hz</span></div>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="ant-descriptions-row">
         <td class="ant-descriptions-item" colspan="1">
            <div class="ant-descriptions-item-container"><span class="ant-descriptions-item-label" style="">Updated Sample Rate</span><span class="ant-descriptions-item-content">16000Hz</span></div>
         </td>
         <td class="ant-descriptions-item" colspan="2">
            <div class="ant-descriptions-item-container"><span class="ant-descriptions-item-label">Channels</span><span class="ant-descriptions-item-content">2</span></div>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

outer HTML at bottom player which the same text `00:01:33` appeared:

```html
<div class="ant-col ant-col-16 AudioPlayer_waveContainer__BHMfg" style="outline: green dotted 2px !important;">
   <div class="ant-row AudioPlayer_alignCenter__11pc_" style="margin-left: -12px; margin-right: -12px; row-gap: 0px;">
      <div class="ant-col AudioPlayer_textAlignRight__3iiTN ant-col-sm-4 ant-col-lg-2" style="padding-left: 12px; padding-right: 12px;"><span style="color: white;">00:00:01</span></div>
      <div class="ant-col ant-col-sm-16 ant-col-lg-20" style="padding-left: 12px; padding-right: 12px;">
         <div id="audioPlayer">
            <wave style="display: block; position: relative; user-select: none; height: 50px; overflow: hidden;">
               <wave style="position: absolute; z-index: 3; left: 0px; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; overflow: hidden; width: 10px; display: block; box-sizing: border-box; border-right: 2px solid rgb(135, 204, 175); pointer-events: none;">
                  <canvas width="943" height="50" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; height: 100%; width: 943px;"></canvas>
               </wave>
               <canvas width="943" height="50" style="position: absolute; z-index: 2; left: 0px; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; height: 100%; pointer-events: none; width: 943px;"></canvas>
            </wave>
            <audio preload="auto" src="https://speech.srs:5088/dir/decoding/49a49899-ba17-4f80-8864-805169c87fca/20140703_dj_mm_p_m_0133/20140703_dj_mm_p_m_0133.wav" style="width: 100%;"></audio>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ant-col ant-col-sm-4 ant-col-lg-2" style="padding-left: 12px; padding-right: 12px;"><span style="color: white;">00:01:33</span></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to apply xpath selector or CSS selector? It's already appearing next to it.

Comment: You can't select by text content with CSS

Comment: yeah i managed to get xpath combination....css or xpath is fine so long I can identify the selector

Answer (score 0):

seems this works:

a very long combination of selectors.

let me know if any better way to do it.

```
//span[@class='ant-descriptions-item-label'][contains(.,'Audio Length')]//following::span[@class='ant-descriptions-item-content' and text()='00:01:33']
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the div contains both the span elements, you could try this to make it a bit shorter.

```
//div[@class=ant-descriptions-item-container and contains(text(), "Audio Length 00:01:33")]
```